# 1D array and 2D array element searching

Tags: python, arrays

I'm creating a lottery program where I generate everything using random number and store them in a 1D array and a 2D array. The first array(1D) contains 8 winning numbers sorted into 2 groups called g1 and g2. The second array(2D) contains the players and their numbers.

For each player from the 2D array I need to determine if they are winners or not by comparing them with the winning numbers. For example if any numbers from the players is also in the winning numbers i need to count them and determine if they are winners of what class.

Their are four classes
class 1 - players with all 6 winning numbers
class 2 - players with any 5 winning numbers
class 3 - players with any 4 winning numbers
class 4 - players with any 3 winning numbers or players with less than 3 numbers from g1 group and has both numbers from the g2 group

if not then they lose

also if the player enters his/her ID it should return the players numbers and also if they are winner or not with the class(1,2,3,4)

```
playerID = 2
playerID = input("Please enter player ID ")
if playerID is in a winner it should return 
     playerID
     playerNum
     winner or not with the class
```

Answer (score 0):

`issubset` can help you match array elements. Do keep in mind that `issubset` does not require the order of the elements to be the same. But exactly that's why I recommended this - because in lottery the order should not matter.

```
Solution= [1,2,3,4] 
userGuess= [1,2,3,4]
otherGuess= [2,3,4]
badGuess= [4,5,6]

if set(userGuess).issubset(set(Solution)):
    return True // TRUE

if set(otherGuess).issubset(set(Solution)):
    return True // TRUE

if set(badGuess).issubset(set(Solution)):
    return True // FALSE
```

You can check length of the array to match if you don't want shorter subsets to be valid.